# How can I get a function to read the next line of a document everytime it's called?

Tags: c++, function, while-loop, io

Really new programmer with a really bad professor here.

I have this code that is supposed to get inputs from a text document (inputsFile) using a function (get_coefficients) and do stuff with it. Currently, everything works perfectly except it reads the same line from the file every time it's executed in the while loop in main. I've google around but I can't find anything that is implementable in my case. I've tried implementing while loops and trying to pass some sort of counting variable but nothing seems to work.

Since this is an assignment for school, I can't do anything fancy. So the more elementary the explanation, the better please, haha. Thank you in advance for any help I get.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//=======================================FUNCTIONS======================================

//a function that displays instructions
void display_instructions() {

 cout << "Enter a, b, c: ";
}

//a function that gathers inputs
void get_coefficients(double& a, double& b, double& c) {
 ifstream inputsFile;
 string inputs;
 string inputString;
 inputsFile.open("textinputs.txt");
     inputsFile >> a >> b >> c;
     cout << a << b << c;
 inputsFile.close();
}
//a function that calculates a discriminant
double calc_discriminant(double a, double b, double c) {
 double discriminant = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
 return discriminant;
}


//a function that calculates root 1
double calc_root_1(double a, double b, double c, double disc) {
 double r1 = ((-b) + (sqrt(disc))) / (2 * a);
 return r1;
}
//a function that calculates root 2
double calc_root_2(double a, double b, double c, double disc) {
 double r2 = ((-b) - (sqrt(disc))) / (2.0 * a);
 return r2;
}

void display(double r1, double r2) {
 cout << "the roots are " << r1 << " and " << r2 << "." << endl;

}

//=======================================EXCECUTE=======================================
int main()
{
 //while again is true
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     double a, b, c;

     display_instructions();

     //run get numbers   
     get_coefficients(a, b, c);

     //if discrimant less than 0 stop the program    
     if (calc_discriminant(a, b, c) < 0) {
         cout << "No real solution" << endl;
     }
     else {   //else get the roots
         double disc = calc_discriminant(a, b, c);
         double r1 = calc_root_1(a, b, c, disc);
         double r2 = calc_root_2(a, b, c, disc);
         //print the roots
         display(r1, r2);
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: The reason it "reads the same line from the file every time it's executed" is because it does exactly that: the function opens the file, and reads the first line from it. Every time it's called that's what it does. If you don't want to do that, then don't do that. Open the file separately, and call this function to read each line from the file, one line at a time. Which part of this is unclear to you?

Comment: Oh, yeah I know it's not doing what it's supposed to, but I don't have the knowledge to change that haha.  That's exactly what I was asking. Just what are some ways I could go about getting it to read each line? Sorry to upset you I'm super new to the language and don't have good resources

Comment: You are opening the file, reading a line then closing the file all in the same function. That function is going to do that every time.

You might want to open the file once in main, then pass the input stream into the `get_coefficients` function each time through.

Comment: Ah, yeah. That would be a much better idea. Thank you, I'll try that!

Comment: Worth noting that you have the same resources as everyone else. You don't have the same experience. Blaming the professor is also only ever part of the story, rarely a big part.

Comment: I guess connections is more so what I meant. I wasn't getting it and really just needed a human you know?   My professor isn't good because I would've turned to him for help but he doesn't want us to haha. But I get what you mean. Learned helplessness gets people nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you do `inputsFile.open()` you're opening the file from the start. You should only open the file once so each time you read from it you'll read the next line from where you were the last time. However, the `ifstream` will be deleted at the end of the scope if you don't save it anywhere. What you can do is initialize the ifstream in `main()` and then pass it to the function by reference so the ifstream will still be there until the program reaches the end of main.

I think this should work for what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
//=======================================FUNCTIONS======================================

//a function that displays instructions
void display_instructions() {

 cout << "Enter a, b, c: ";
}

//a function that gathers inputs
void get_coefficients(double& a, double& b, double& c, ifstream& inputsFile) {
 string inputs;
 string inputString;
     inputsFile >> a >> b >> c;
     cout << a << b << c;
}
//a function that calculates a discriminant
double calc_discriminant(double a, double b, double c) {
 double discriminant = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
 return discriminant;
}


//a function that calculates root 1
double calc_root_1(double a, double b, double c, double disc) {
 double r1 = ((-b) + (sqrt(disc))) / (2 * a);
 return r1;
}
//a function that calculates root 2
double calc_root_2(double a, double b, double c, double disc) {
 double r2 = ((-b) - (sqrt(disc))) / (2.0 * a);
 return r2;
}

void display(double r1, double r2) {
 cout << "the roots are " << r1 << " and " << r2 << "." << endl;

}

//=======================================EXCECUTE=======================================
int main()
{
    ifstream inputsFile;
    inputsFile.open("textinputs.txt");
    //while again is true
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         double a, b, c;

         display_instructions();

         //run get numbers
         get_coefficients(a, b, c, inputsFile);

         //if discrimant less than 0 stop the program
         if (calc_discriminant(a, b, c) < 0) {
             cout << "No real solution" << endl;
         }
         else {   //else get the roots
             double disc = calc_discriminant(a, b, c);
             double r1 = calc_root_1(a, b, c, disc);
             double r2 = calc_root_2(a, b, c, disc);
             //print the roots
             display(r1, r2);
        }
    }
    inputsFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is exaclty what I was trying to do. I forgot I could use ifstream in function parentheses. Thank you so much for your time and effort.